# NLog.config will not build in output folder of a separate project that references my NLog Wrapper Class.dll

Tags: c#, nlog, nlog.config

I have a class library that is a wrapper for NLog. I compile this into a dll, which I would like to share with other applications. I would like applications to be able to reference just this dll to use the logging features that it provides. *I have the settings Build Action:Content and Copy to Output Directory:Copy always for the NLog.config in NLogWrapperClass, set prior to build.

If a project references this dll and both exist in the same solution, the project will build the NLog.config folder to it's output folder, and everything works well.

The problem is:
When I reference this dll from a project in a separate solution, and both the dll and project are not in the same solution, NLog.config does not get built to the project output directory. And logging does not work.

Does anyone know how I can get NLog.config to the build to the output folder of the project referencing my NLogWrapperClass.dll, from a separate solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've researched a bit and my other options seem to be to ship the config file with the dll or setup the NLog configuration through code, both of which I would like to try and avoid if possible.

Comment: If the DLL requires a config file, then the config file needs to be added to the startup project (Web application/windows application). The config file will not be automatically added to the referencing project. Example, if you are using NLog or Log4Net directly in your project, you need to create the config file in the project and write the config there.... the log4net.config or NLog.config will not be generated by automatically.

Comment: got it. appreciate the info